# Please help me with this recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

```
void myMethod( int counter) {
    if(counter == 0)
        return;
    else {
        System.out.println("hello" + counter);
        myMethod(--counter);
        System.out.println("" + counter);
        //return;
    }
}
```

The output for this when I pass a 3 to the function is going to be

```
hello3
hello2
hello1
0
1
2
```

I understand why output has hello3 hello2 hello1, but why 0 1 2? When the counter decrease from 3 to 0, then it should get into the if and return, right? How could the program get to the `System.out.println("" + counter)` line?

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code as it runs

Comment: When all the calls of `myMethod` resolve from the stack, the print statements will execute

Comment: Every function call has its own variable `counter`; and in general `f(x)` will _never_ modify the variable's value. (If the value is a more complex object, it might change a field though)

Comment: The return statement doesn't exit all the methods at once, it just exits the current invocation so the caller can continue.

Comment: If the code can reach the first `println` statement, it will also reach the second `println` statement (eventually), since there is no `return` statement between them. For every `helloN` message, a corresponding `N` message will be printed.

Comment: The recursion takes you to the top of the stack where the counter is 0. Then it unwinds from zero printing the count as it was when you were building the stack. I recommend writing this out on paper before even getting to a debug session as it will be very clear why you're where you are and why the state is as it is.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that has meaning. Your current title says nothing about the question you're asking or problem you're having. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to a future reader when seen in a list of search results. *please help me with this* is useless for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's recursive and the recursive call comes before your printline, it will recursively call itself over and over until it reaches the base case. Only first after the recursive calls have ended will your print be allowed to execute.

Something like this

```
Do something
   first recursive call
   Do something
      second recursive call
      Do something
         third recursive call
         Ending recursive
      Ending recursive
   Ending Recursive
```

First here will the entire method stop, but as you can se, the basecases / the end of the recursive calls, will actually execute inside the other recursive methods, so what you see in form on 012 is the rows executed after the recursion has ended.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not doing homework, I am just learning java by myself now. I am in the army not school, do not have a professor.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening, is once the code executes
 `myMethod(--counter);`

It executes the print out after it, so each time the counter value is not 0, this code will always be called, once the other recursive functions have finished. Every time you hit that `else {` block, all the code within it will be executed, `System.out.println("" + counter)` is just printed last, because you have the recursive call right before it, and that code is executed first.

If you set a breakpoint in your IDE, and run the debugger, you will get a clearer look at what is happening.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, but I still have one more question. Why System.out.println("" + counter) executed three times, what is the condition stopped it?

Comment: If your code enters that `else` block, there is no way for that line of code to not run. The only way for that code to not run is to add `return;` on the line before it. But then it would never be called at all. Again I recommend for you to use a debugger to help you see what is actually happening.